# Updating a model instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to understand what the correct way to update a model instance is, using mongoose, ie:

Having:

```
User = {
   username: {
      type: String,
      indexed: true
   },
   email: {
      type: String,
      indexed: true
   },
   name: String,
   .........
};
```

I'm sending the whole form through ajax to a controller.
So far, i know of two options:

```
app.put('/users/', function(req, res){
   var id = ObjectId(req.body._id);
   User.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, user){
       user.name = req.body.name;
       ....
       ....
       user.save();
   });
});
```

or:

```
app.put('/users/', function(req, res){
    var id = ObjectId(req.body._id);
    delete req.body._id
    User.update({_id: id}, req.body, function(err){
         .....
    };
});
```

Both ways have disadvantages:
In the first approach i have to map all properties one by one;
In the second approach i have to delete all properties that can't be changed;
there is a third possible approach that would make me send from client-side, only the changed properties, but i think that would be a big hassle to.

Is there a good, standardized way that i'm not seeing, to do this?

Thanks

Comment: to the person who voted down: at least you could explain your vote in the comment...

Answer (score 2):

This is the approach I typically use, it involves a small npm package called mongoose-mass-assignement:

https://github.com/bhelx/mongoose-mass-assignment

The docs are pretty self explanatory, easy to use. It basically does the delete for you. So you add `protected:true` to your model, and then it deletes those properties for you. I like this approach because it still allows me to use the req.body as is. You can use this for updates and inserts as well.

Comment: seems cool, thought it adds a little overhead having to update my code  everywhere to use massAssign.

Comment: oh, one question, it's not covered in the docs, do you still have to delete body._id?

Comment: You don't have to delete anything anymore, if you're asking if you need to "protect" id, then my answer would you be yea, might as well. I don't see the harm in doing it....

Answer (score 1):

A variant of the first approach is to use underscore's [`extend`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend) method to apply all properties of the body to your model instance:

```
app.put('/users/', function(req, res){
   var id = ObjectId(req.body._id);
   User.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, user){
       _.extend(user, req.body);
       user.save();
   });
});
```

However, be sure to delete any properties you don't want the user to be able to set from `req.body` first.

Comment: thanks, but that way has the same hassles from my first approach. Nice would be to have a method that does the opposite from extend, ie, create a third object that only had the properties that differed from the same two

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez Not sure what you mean about the same hassles as the first approach.  You no longer need to map them one by one.

Comment: i was talking about the hassles of the second approach, the delete ones